# How can I mock a file upload in nestjs?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nestjs

I have a method in my controller that accepts a csv file sent as form-data.

```
import csv = require('csvtojson');

@Post('/create')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async createUsers(@Query() query: RequestDTO, @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File) {
 const createJson = await csv().fromString(file.buffer.toString('utf-8'));
 const response = this.myService.createUsers(query, createJson);
 return response;
}
```

I just want to be able to mock it using Jest but I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply forge `file` parameter with the correct properties.

```js
const file: Express.Multer.File = {
  originalname: 'file.csv',
  mimetype: 'text/csv',
  path: 'something',
  buffer: Buffer.from('one,two,three'),
};
```

In your test file when you call your `createUser` you can pass it as a second parameter

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378761/how-to-mock-multer-using-jest-enzyme-to-file-upload-using-axios-post-mock-call) could be helpful

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't clear from the other answer but yours helped